# Forwarding requests from one web service to another

Tags: java, jboss, jax-rpc

So the case is the following:

I have an application that communicates with a JAX-RPC web service (Hosted in an .ear package on a JBoss server). We had a requirement of moving all the operations in this web service to a new one with a new name, keeping in mind that we should keep our backward compatibility with clients with the old web service stub. The idea is that I shouldn't keep the logic of the operations in both web services, and instead, try to forward the requests for older clients from the old web service to the new one. I found a solution, but I don't know what are its downsides: I kept the skeleton of the operations in the old web service, and in my ejbCreate(), I created an instance of the bean of the new web service, and now all I do is invoking the operations of the new web service using this bean instance (passing the same arguments as received from the client without running any logic). Is my solution valid? Are there any better alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not to use ws-addressing? did you read about it ? (honestly I never used it, but I know it can be used to proxy requests)

Comment: Never heard of it. Would this be a valid solution when both web services exist in the same web application? Or is this irrelevant?

Comment: As I said, I never used it. I think that there should be an URI in the addressing information, so I don't see a reason for it not to work within the same container (and even in the same webapp). google WS-Addressing and read about it, wiki might be a good starting point. BTW - WS-* is a mess and it is difficult to get these things to work, specially when using exotic and old WS stacks like old jbossws. please let us know your findings and good luck

Comment: Thanks a lot for the heads-up. I will update you with whatever I find. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but here is a better answer for fellow googlers:

Check out membrane-soa reverse proxy: http://www.membrane-soa.org/reverse-soap-proxy.htm

To solve the exact problem in question check this doc: http://www.membrane-soa.org/service-proxy-doc/4.0/soap-quickstart.htm